# What does it mean by parameterized constructor with default value?

Tags: c++, constructor

I am learning c++. I made this program but on compiling it, the program shows ambigious error. 
I don't understand that if i am making an object with no arguments then it should only call default constructor & the program should run without any error. Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class room
{
 int length,width;
 public:
 room()
 {
  cout<<"Default constructor"; 
 } 
 room(int l=0)
 {
      cout<<"Constructor"; //the compiler is taking this also as default constructor
 }
 room(int l=0,int w=0)
 {
  cout<<"Constructor";  //the compiler is taking this also as default constructor on making other two as comment
 }
};
int main()
{
 room r1;
 return 0;
}
```

I have tried this code on compiler like Codeblocks, Dev c++ & GCC also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`room r1` is ambiguous because a constructor with all parameters defaulted is already available
as `room()` as a default constructor

**§ 12.1**

> A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that
>   can be **called without an argument**. If there is no user-declared
>   constructor for class X, a constructor having no parameters is
>   implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4).

Comment: Thank you sir for your response. I just want to confirm now that zero is parameter with deefault value?

Answer (score 0):

You have  3 constructors which could be called without supplying any arguments.
So the compiler gets confused by these 3 constructors.